# Assign onchange to an object and pass a parameter

Tags: javascript

So I have the following JavaScript:

```
<script language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form){
        var val=form.profile.options[form.profile.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location='?profile=' + val ;
    }
    function init(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myform");
        document.getElementById("id_profile").onchange = reload(form);
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

But then it keeps on reloading itself constantly. Which is expected. But how can I assign `reload` and pass a function instance to it?

I could do:

```
<script language=JavaScript>
    function reload(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myform");
        var val=form.profile.options[form.profile.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location='?profile=' + val ;
    }
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("id_profile").onchange = reload;
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

But what if I have more forms? Or I let say I want to reuse `reload` on multiple pages with different form names.

I would like to avoid setting onchange in the HTML tag though:

```
onchange="reload(this.form)"
```

If this is possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what if I have more forms?

You can assign the same function to all the `profile` elements in the forms, and reference the element that received the change event inside the function using `this`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reload(){
        // In here, "this" is the element that received the event

        var val = this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].value;
        self.location='?profile=' + val ;
    }
    function init(){
        var len = document.forms.length;
        while( len-- ) {
            document.forms[ len ].profile.onchange = reload;
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function that returns a function (a closure) for the reload function.

```
function reload(form){
    return function(){
      var val=form.profile.options[form.profile.options.selectedIndex].value;
      self.location='?profile=' + val ;
    }
}
function init(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myform");
    document.getElementById("id_profile").onchange = reload(form);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: ha, i can't decide which answer to go for... :) I like Patricks solution, it's so simple, I didn't know about `this`. But you also gave a good example of returning a function, which is nice too (All JS business is new to me)...

Comment: @pulgium: This solution from @Rocket definitely works as well. It requires more overhead, but has a certain geek-coolness to it. :o)

Comment: @pulgium: @patrick's is probably a better choice here.  Because you are using just 1 function, compared to making a new one each time.